# Rspec - enabling/disabling class macro between tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I have an app which uses Devise, but the `confirmable` module is configurable within the application

```
class User
  devise :confirmable if MyApp::Config[:confirmable]
end
```

Now I want to test this with Rspec but the problem I'm having is if I set `MyApp::Config[:confirmable]` before the suite is run, I can't then change it between tests because the `User` class is only evaluated once, at the start of the entire suite. If `MyApp::Config[:confirmable]` is `true`, changing it to `false` in a before block has no effect.

I tried ignoring the configurable aspect and setting it to `false`, then in a test where I want to test when the option is enabled, I did this:

```
before do
  User.class_eval { devise :confirmable }
end
```

This works for this test, but for every test after, the user has the `confirmable` option enabled, and so it breaks tests relying on it to be disabled.

I think what I want to do is something like this:

```
describe "My Test" 
  before do
    MyApp::Config[:confirmable] = true
    # RELOAD RAILS ENVIRONMENT
  end

  after do
    MyApp::Config[:confirmable] = false
    # RELOAD RAILS ENVIRONMENT
  end
end
```

Is this possible? Is there a better way of doing what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing my config variable and then reloading the class. I made this into a spec helper:

```
def set_confirmable_option(value)
   MyApp::Config[:confirmable] = value
   Object.send(:remove_const, 'User')
   load File.expand_path("../../../app/models/user.rb", __FILE__)
end
```

Then in my tests I could do

```
before { set_confirmable_option(true) }
```